# Embedded expression (JSON/YML) with default value

Tags: karate

Karate offers an API method *get* to obtain a variable value or a default one if the former does not exist as **karate.get("anyVariable", "default value")**.

I would want to know if there is any similar behaviour to apply to **read** embedded expressions in a JSON or YML file or just as declaring a new json variable that mimicks these kind of feature.

I have been reading the docs and trying some stuff like this:

`* def defaultvar = { key: #(notdefinedvariable || 'defaultValue') }`

or within a external *yml* file something like this:

```
id: 1
random: '#(somevariable)'
defaultvale: '#(notdefinedvariable || defaultValue)'
```

I've tried some different combinations and expressions without success, so I don't know really if it's supported. I think would be useful and would up to contribute if needed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually `karate.get()` is "available" within embedded expressions, so you can do this in a JSON file:

```
{
    "foo": "#(karate.get('foo', 'default'))"
}
```

Personally I feel that you should pre-set any variables and defaults *before* you read a file, something like this:

```
* def foo = karate.get('foo', 'default')
* def response = read('test.json')
```

And the file:

```
{
    "foo": "#(foo)"
}
```

And yes, you can define a custom function if you don't want to type so many characters and do more logic, but I don't think this saves you much:

```
* def getOr = function(x, y){ return karate.get(x, y) }
* def response = read('test.json')
```

And then the JSON file:

```
{
    "foo": "#(getOr('foo', 'default'))"
}
```